# Strange color shift after loading a GL_RGB texture

Tags: opengl, texture2d

Here's a primitive 5x2 texture, defined in RGB and RGBA formats.

```
//                       1               2               3                     4               5
unsigned char rgb[]  = { 0, 0, 0,        0, 0, 0,        200, 200, 200,        0, 0, 0,        200, 200, 200,
                         0, 0, 0,        0, 0, 0,        200, 200, 200,        0, 0, 0,        200, 200, 200,       };
unsigned char rgba[] = { 0, 0, 0, 255,   0, 0, 0, 255,   200, 200, 200, 255,   0, 0, 0, 255,   200, 200, 200, 255,
                         0, 0, 0, 255,   0, 0, 0, 255,   200, 200, 200, 255,   0, 0, 0, 255,   200, 200, 200, 255,  };
```

Loading the RGBA version works as expected:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,       // mipmap level
             GL_RGB,  // dest format
             5,       // width
             2,       // height
             0,       // deprecated
             GL_RGBA, // source format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             rgba);
```

[image]

Loading the RGB texture results in a weird color shift:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,       // mipmap level
             GL_RGB,  // dest format
             5,       // width
             2,       // height
             0,       // deprecated
             GL_RGB,  // source format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             rgb);
```

[image]

The difference in the code between the first and the second screenshot are just those two arguments to glTexImage2D.

What am I doing wrong?

**Environment**

- ATI Radeon HD5450, OpenGL 4.2
- Windows 7, 64-Bit
- Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Did you set the pack alignment? Default is 4 bytes, so the rgba array will be OK, but it won't work with the rgb array.

Comment: No. What arguments to glPixelStorei would fix this issue?

Comment: [See here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads) -- `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks so much! Add an official answer, if you like. I'll gladly vote you up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[See here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads) -- `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` should fix it.